# Google logo, map tiles and other google images don’t load in Chrome (HTTP 400)

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-code-400

There are several similar entries in stackoverflow for this error (HTTP 400), but I haven't found anything relevant to mine; so if this is already answered... my apologies.

Chrome is my default browser, and I use many Google services everyday, like Gmail, Maps, Docs, etc.

However, time-to-time, when I am logged-in to Google, I notice some assets are not loading from Google websites (*.google.com).

For example; Google logo in upper-left corner at main www.google.com search results; or image tiles in Maps.

Those missing images (or assets in general images, JS, CSS) have references in the DevTools Console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400`

Once I clear storage in DevTools > Application, naturally I get logged out, but those missing assets start behaving normal and load as expected. I can log back in to Google services and use them without any issues, until next time it happens.

Since clearing storage (cookies and cache) fixes the issue, I don't think it's related with any of the installed add-ons (read AdBlock).

Has anyone experienced this issue, or better yet have a solution for this? Or should I continue blaming Google in general? :)

Comment: The same thing is happening to me ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was having a similar issue in Maps. I searched around on the intertubes and found a solution that worked for me:
   https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/zbT4TK4x2QI

Synopsis: delete all the cookies for "www.google.com" starting with gsScrollPos

In Chrome:

1. click "three dot" menu on upper right
2. click settings
3. open the advanced section
4. click content settings
5. click cookies
6. click "see all cookies and site data"
7. click the search cookies box and type "google"
8. scroll down to find "www.google.com" and click it
9. now click the X next to each item starting with gsScrollPos

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Also, you might want to edit the title to add "Google Maps not loading map tiles" or the like to the subject?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RyanPrescott. As soon as I get access to my laptop, I’ll try your suggestion and post an update here.

Comment: This also prevented the google logo from loading on my default search page, similar error 400. I had the maps issue yesterday. Suggested solution resolved both complaints.